# mysql: Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

When I run

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

I get

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I searched it online and applied almost all solutions which did not resolve my issue:

```
sudo reboot
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt purge mysql-client-core-8.0  mysql-server-core-8.0
sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
# shows empty
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/mysql/
sudo apt autopurge
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client

sudo chmod -R u+rwx /etc/mysql/
sudo chown -R mysql.mysql /etc/mysql/
sudo chmod 0640 /var/log/mysql/error.log
# chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mysql/error.log': No such file or directory
sudo chmod 0750 /var/log/mysql
# chmod: cannot access '/var/log/mysql': No such file or directory
sudo chmod 0755 /var
sudo chmod 0775 /var/log
sudo chown mysql:adm /var/log/mysql
# chown: cannot access '/var/log/mysql': No such file or directory
sudo chown mysql:adm /var/log/mysql/error.log
# chown: cannot access '/var/log/mysql/error.log': No such file or directory
sudo chown root:root /var
sudo chown root:syslog /var/log
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/*
# chown: cannot access '/var/log/mysql/*': No such file or directory
```

trying again:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

checks

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
df -h --total

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            948M     0  948M   0% /dev
tmpfs           199M  1.5M  198M   1% /run
/dev/sda2        98G   56G   38G  61% /
tmpfs           994M     0  994M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           994M     0  994M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop1       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/20400
/dev/loop4       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11841
/dev/loop5       71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/20450
git             476G  428G   48G  91% /media/sf_git
share           476G  428G   48G  91% /media/sf_share
tmpfs           199M   44K  199M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0         58M   58M     0 100% /media/ar/VBox_GAs_6.1.12
total           1.1T  913G  135G  88% -
```

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-05-26 05:02:47 AEST; 35s ago
    Process: 56094 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

```
sudo journalctl -xe

-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 10868 and the job result is done.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 05:02:47 myser systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 10868 and the job result is failed.
May 26 05:03:23 myser sudo[56095]:       ar : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ar/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status mysql.service
May 26 05:03:23 myser sudo[56095]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 26 05:03:24 myser sudo[56095]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 26 05:05:03 myser sudo[56101]:       ar : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ar/Desktop ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
May 26 05:05:03 myser sudo[56101]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

It has not logged anything

```
sudo tail -30 /var/log/mysql/error.log

tail: cannot open '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
(empty result: bad)
```

```
whereis mysql

mysql: /usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mariadb
(empty: good)
```

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql

ii  mysql-client                               8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     all          MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-client-8.0                           8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-8.0                      8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                               5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2                            all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server                               8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-8.0                           8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-8.0                      8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     amd64        MySQL database server binaries
```

also

```
journalctl -xe | tail -20 

-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 11804 and the job result is done.
May 26 05:21:49 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 26 05:21:49 myser systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 26 05:21:49 myser systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 11804 and the job result is failed.
```

Trying config manipulation:

sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20M
```

then try again:

```
sudo service mysql start

Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Note: I used to have mariadb but removed it completely.

Comment: Why were you fiddling around with permissions on the `/var/log` directories? Many server applications *hate* that and will refuse to write when expected locations for files are misconfigured. If you are running MySQL on a standard Ubuntu install and haven’t modified its system account, then proper owner:group values are `mysql:mysql` 

Comment: @matigo, for me, `ll /var | grep log` shows `drwxrwxr-x 15 root syslog   4096 May 26 09:05 log/`. I created `/var/log/mysql/` and gave it `mysql:mysql` permission and the problem still persists. Any idea?